# Understanding about the grazing paddock in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

Please take a look at the following [quote](https://youtu.be/CT_N_IK0kyA):

> I do not want to see a transient serfdom of European peoples in which every serf competes in a race towards the bottom. Being in the EU gives the illusion of opportunity when in reality all it does is make one's grazing paddock slightly bigger.

I don't understand what would be wrong with a slightly bigger grazing paddock that might be the reality of being in the EU. After all, we all or at least most of us would want something bigger. What's wrong with the reality then? The fact that's only **slightly** bigger? Or is there something else that I can't figure out?

Comment: (In her opinion) it's only slightly bigger, but at what cost?

Comment: Given the mention of "the illusion of opportunity", my interpretation is that she means that (in her opinion) people in the EU will *think* at first that they have more opportunities to improve their lives in substantial ways, when really all they will get is perhaps slightly more of what they have now.